# C++11 smart pointer 'library'

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

Edit: NOTE I'm a C++ "beginner" still in undergrad trying to teach myself modern C++ (because they don't do that in uni) so I'm sure this is riddled with errors that I am unaware of.

Made a *subset* of std's smart pointer library (unique, shared, and weak, denoted as unq, shr, and weak) in a very minimal header file. This is mostly for fun and as a learning experience but looking to improve in any way, thanks!

**ptr.h**

```
#ifndef PTRLIB_H                                                                                                        
#define PTRLIB_H                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

#include <cstdint>                                                                                                      
#include <atomic>                                                                                                       
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

namespace ptr                                                                                                           
{                                                                                                                               
    template<typename T>                                                                                                    
    class base //for methods common to all smart ptr types                                                                  
    {                                                                                                                                               
        protected:                                                                                                                      
            mutable T * obj;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

            //non instatiable outside the header                                                                                     
            base() {}                                                                                                               
            base(T * obj) : obj(obj) {}                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

            virtual void operator = (T * obj) { this->obj = obj; }                                                                                                                                                                                  

        public:                                                                                                                         
            //unq uses these versions                                                                                               
            virtual void reset() { delete this->obj; this->obj = nullptr; }                                                         
            virtual void reset(T * obj) { delete this->obj; this->obj = obj; }                                                                                                                                                                              

            inline T * get() { return obj; }                                                                                                                                                                                                                

            operator bool const () { return (obj != nullptr) ? true : false; }                                                                                                                                                                              

            bool operator == (const base<T> rhs) { return obj == rhs.obj; }                                                         
            bool operator != (const base<T> rhs) { return obj != rhs.obj; }                                                         
            bool operator <= (const base<T> rhs) { return obj <= rhs.obj; }                                                         
            bool operator >= (const base<T> rhs) { return obj >= rhs.obj; }                                                         
            bool operator < (const base<T> rhs) { return obj < rhs.obj; }                                                           
            bool operator > (const base<T> rhs) { return obj > rhs.obj; }                                                                                                                                                                                   

            std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & stream) { return (std::cout << obj); }                                                                                                                                           
    };                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

    template<typename T>                                                                                                    
    class unq : public base<T>                                                                                              
    {                                                                                                                               
        public:                                                                                                                         
            unq() {}                                                                                                                
            unq(T * obj) : base<T>(obj) {}                                                                                          
            unq(const unq<T> & u) : base<T>(u.obj) { u.obj = nullptr; }
            ~unq() { delete this->obj; }                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

            T * release()                                                                                                           
            {                                                                                                                               
                T * temp = this->obj;                                                                                                   
                this->obj = nullptr;                                                                                                    
                return temp;                                                                                                    
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

            //don't want weak to be able to access the object so duplicated in shr                                                  
            inline T * operator -> () { return this->obj; }                                                                         
            inline T & operator * () { return *(this->obj); }                                                       
    };                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

    template<typename T>                                                                                                    
    class weak; //class forwarding for friend class                                                                                                                                                                                                 

    template<typename T>                                                                                                    
    class shr : public base<T>                                                                                              
    {                                                                                                                               
        private:                                                                                                                        
            friend class weak<T>;                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

            //reference counter                                                                                                     
            mutable std::atomic<int32_t> * refs;                                                                                                                                                                                                            

            inline bool is_last() { return ((refs == nullptr && this->obj == nullptr) || *refs == 1); }                                                                                                                                             

        public:                                                                                                                         
            shr()                                                                                                                   
            { refs = new std::atomic<int32_t>, *refs = 1; }                                                                                                                                                                                                 

            shr(T * obj) : base<T>(obj)                                                                                             
            { refs = new std::atomic<int32_t>, *refs = 1; }                                                                                                                                                                                                 

            shr(const shr<T> & s) : base<T>(s.obj)                                                                                  
            { refs = (s.refs != nullptr) ? s.refs : new std::atomic<int32_t>, *refs += 1; }                                                                                                                                                                 

            shr(const weak<T> & w) : base<T>(w.obj)                                                                                 
            { refs = (w.refs != nullptr) ? w.refs : new std::atomic<int32_t>, *refs += 1; }                                                                                                                                                                 

            ~shr()                                                                                                                  
            {                                                                                                                               
                if (is_last())                                                                                                          
                {                                                                                                                               
                    delete this->obj; this->obj = nullptr;                                                                                  
                    delete refs; refs = nullptr;                                                                                    
                }                   
                else *refs -= 1;                                                                                                
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

            void operator = (T * obj)                                                                                               
            {                                                                                                                               
                this->obj = obj;                                                                                                        
                *refs = 1;                                                                                                      
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

            void operator = (const shr<T> & s)                                                                                      
            {                                                                                                                               
                this->obj = s.obj;                                                                                                      
                refs = (s.refs != nullptr) ? s.refs : new std::atomic<int32_t>, *refs += 1;                                     
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

            void operator = (const weak<T> & w)                                                                                     
            {                                                                                                                               
                this->obj = w.obj;                                                                                                      
                refs = (w.refs != nullptr) ? w.refs : new std::atomic<int32_t>, *refs += 1;                                     
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

            void reset()                                                                                                            
            {                                                                                                                               
                if (is_last())                                                                                                          
                {                                                                                                                               
                    delete this->obj; this->obj = nullptr;                                                                                  
                    delete refs; refs = nullptr;                                                                                    
                }                                                                                                                       
                else                                                                                                                    
                {                                                                                                                               
                    this->obj = nullptr;                                                                                                    
                    *refs -= 1; refs = nullptr;                                                                                     
                }                                                                                                               
            }       

            void reset(T * obj)                                                                                                     
            {                                                                                                                               
                if (is_last()) { delete this->obj; delete refs; }                                                                       
                else *refs -= 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

                this->obj = obj;                                                                                                        
                refs = new std::atomic<int32_t>, *refs = 1;                                                                     
            }     

            inline const int32_t use_count() { return static_cast<int32_t>(*refs); }                                                
            inline bool unique() { return (*refs == 1); }                                                                           
            inline T * operator -> () { return this->obj; } 
            inline T & operator * () { return *(this->obj); }                                                       
    };                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

    template<typename T>                                                                                                    
    class weak : public base<T>                                                                                             
    {                                                                                                                               
        private:                                                                                                                        
            friend class shr<T>;                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

            mutable std::atomic<int32_t> * refs;                                                                                                                                                                                                    

        public:                                                                                                                         
            weak() {}                                                                                                               
            weak(T * obj) : base<T>(obj) {}                                                                                         
            weak(const weak<T> & w) : base<T>(w->obj) {}                                                                            
            weak(const shr<T> & s) : base<T>(s.obj), refs(s.refs) {}

            void operator = (T * obj) { this->obj = obj; }                                                                          
            void operator = (const shr<T> & s) { this->obj = s.obj; refs = s.refs; }                                                void operator = (const weak<T> & w) { this->obj = w.obj; refs = w.refs; }                                                                                                                                                                       
            void reset() { this->obj = nullptr; refs = nullptr; }                                                                   
            void reset(T * obj) { this->obj = obj; refs = new std::atomic<int32_t>; *refs = 0; }                                                                                                                                                            

            inline shr<T> lock() { return shr<T>(this->obj); }                                                                      
            inline bool expired() { return ((refs == nullptr || *refs <= 0) ? true : false); }                                      
            inline const int32_t use_count() { return ((expired()) ? 0 : static_cast<int32_t>(*refs)); }            
    };                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

    template<typename T>                                                                                                    
    const shr<T> make_shr(T * obj) { return shr<T>(obj); }                                                                                                                                                                                          

    template<typename T>                                                                                                    
    const unq<T> make_unq(T * obj) { return unq<T>(obj); }                                                          
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
#endif
```

Comment: Quite a lot missing [Have a look here](https://lokiastari.com/blog/2014/12/30/c-plus-plus-by-example-smart-pointer/index.html) [And here](https://lokiastari.com/blog/2015/01/15/c-plus-plus-by-example-smart-pointer-part-ii/index.html) [and constructors](https://lokiastari.com/blog/2015/01/23/c-plus-plus-by-example-smart-pointer-part-iii/index.html)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'll hit the red flags first, and then review the details.

```
template<typename T>                                                                                                    
const shr<T> make_shr(T * obj) { return shr<T>(obj); }
```

"Returning by `const` value" is a red flag. It doesn't do anything except occasionally disable move semantics. So at least we remove the `const`. But also, where there's one bug there's two. So we probably compare your `make_shr<T>(...)` to the Standard Library's `make_shared<T>(...)` and find out that your code does something *vastly* different. Consider

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sp = std::make_shared<int>(0);
assert(sp != nullptr);
ptr::shr<int> ps = ptr::make_shr<int>(0);
assert(ps == nullptr);
```

---

Well, actually I don't think `ps == nullptr` even compiles with your version, because your comparison operators only ever take `base<T>`, and the implicit conversion from `nullptr_t` to `base<T>` is `protected` so normal code can't use it. You should have a public conversion from `std::nullptr_t`, and it should express the idea that you don't *take ownership of* "null"; it's a special state without an owned object.

---

```
base(T * obj) : obj(obj) {}
```

Each constructor should be `explicit` unless your goal is specifically to add an implicit conversion. Make this one `explicit`.

---

```
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & stream) { return (std::cout << obj); }
```

The red flag here is that this operator is completely backwards and broken. What you meant was

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const base<T>& p) {
    stream << p.get();
    return stream;
}
```

Always use ADL friend functions to implement your operators (except for the few that have to be member functions, such as `operator++`).

Where there's one bug there's two (or more).

- Your version was streaming to `std::cout` regardless of which `stream` was passed in.
- "If it's not tested, it doesn't work." Even the very simplest test case would have shown that the version you wrote wasn't functional. If you don't plan to write tests for (or: don't plan to use) a feature, such as `operator<<`, then you might as well save time and just not write the feature!
- Iostreams sucks: Even my new version is broken for `ptr::shr<char>`. I mean, `std::cout << my_shr_ptr_to_char` will end up calling `operator<<(ostream&, char*)`, which will *not* print the pointer — it'll print the *thing it points to*, treated as a C string, which it almost certainly isn't. So it'll segfault and die. The simplest way to work around *that* is to make sure our code controls the exact overload of `operator<<` that we call: don't let it be template-dependent. So:

  ```
  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const base<T>& p) {
      stream << static_cast<void*>(p.get());
      return stream;
  }
  ```

---

```
operator bool const () { return (obj != nullptr) ? true : false; }
```

This is a sneaky one I'd never seen before! You put the `const` in front of the `()` instead of behind it; so, this is another example of "returning by `const` value." What you meant to type was

```
operator bool () const { return (obj != nullptr) ? true : false; }
```

that is, a `const` member function (which promises not to modify the `this` object), that returns (non-const-qualified) `bool`.

Stylistically, there's no sense in writing `condition ? true : false` — that's like saying `if condition is true, return true; if condition is false, return false`. So:

```
operator bool () const { return (obj != nullptr); }
```

---

```
inline T * get() { return obj; }
```

Any time a function promises not to modify one of its reference parameters, you should make sure to `const`-qualify that parameter's referent. So, `void f(int *p)` is saying it might modify `*p`; `void f(const int *p)` is saying it promises *not* to modify `*p`. Similarly for any member function that promises not to modify its `*this` parameter: `void mf()` is saying it *might* modify `*this`; `void mf() const` is saying it promises *not* to modify `*this`.

```
T *get() const { return obj; }
```

I also removed the `inline` keyword because it wasn't doing anything. Functions defined in the body of a class, like this, Java/Python-style, are already inline by default. The only time you need `inline` is when you want to define a function *in* a header file but *outside* the body of a class.

---

That's enough red flags. Let me mention one super bug and then I'll call it a night.

```
class weak : public base<T> {
[...]
    mutable std::atomic<int32_t> * refs;
[...]
    [no destructor declared]
};
```

Having an RAII type like `weak` without a destructor is an oxymoron. `weak` *must* have a destructor to clean up its `refs` member, or else you'll have a leak.
(Also, `refs` doesn't need to be `mutable`.)

But wait, does `weak` even own its `refs` at all? Its constructor doesn't call `new`, so maybe it's okay that its destructor doesn't call `delete`?... Right. `weak::refs` is always initialized to point the same place as some `shr`'s `refs` pointer. `weak::refs` is just an observer; `shr::refs` is the owner of the `atomic<int32_t>`.

But any time we have a non-owning observer, we should think about *dangling*. Can `weak::refs` dangle? Yes, it certainly can!

```
ptr::shr<int> p(new int(42));
ptr::weak<int> w(p);
p.reset();
w.expired();  // segfault
ptr::shr<int> q(w.lock());
assert(q != ptr::shr<int>(nullptr));
*q;  // segfault
```

But your `weak` is all screwed up. Since it's unusable, you should just remove it. Bring it back if you ever run into a case where you need to use something like `weak_ptr`, so that you have some idea of what the requirements are. (For example, "locking an expired `weak_ptr` should return null," or "locking an unexpired `weak_ptr` should increment the original refcount, not create a new refcount competing with the first," or "it is nonsensical to create a `weak_ptr` from a raw `T*`."

Write some test cases for your `ptr::unq` and `ptr::shr`. You'll find bugs. Think about how to fix those bugs, and then (only then!) fix them. As you improve your understanding of *what* the code needs to do, you'll improve your coding style as well.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the review! And yea I had a little trouble wrapping my head around how std::weak worked and my implementation here is the result of that. Do you have any tips for effectively implementing it if I try to keep it?

Comment: Also, any critiques on how the program is structured overall? I feel like I could've done it a bit more efficiently but not exactly sure where.

Other sidenote (sorry), I also used mutable for reference counters when taking in const arguments in the constructors, not sure if there is another way around that or if just remove the 'const' altogether?

Comment: "Do you have any tips for effectively implementing [`weak_ptr`]?" Sort of. Does ["buy my book"](https://www.amazon.com/Mastering-17-STL-standard-components/dp/178712682X) count as a tip? ;) `weak_ptr` is explained, with diagrams and source code, in Chapter 6.

Comment: "I also used mutable for reference counters when taking in const arguments in the constructors" — This comment makes no sense to me. Just remove the `mutable` and recompile; it'll be fine.

Comment: @sjh919: Note that there are a lot more dangling/memory leak issues than the ones mentioned in this answer (e.g. `auto ptr = ptr::unq<int>(new int); ptr = new int;` leaks the old value and will `delete` the new one two times!). Also, why have a (non-working) copy contructor for `ptr::unq`? // @Quuxplusone: You might want to add a small section on the other parts of the rule of five ;)

Comment: To be fair, a common way to test `<<` is with `std::cout`, so it's not nearly as "stupid" as you make it sound to have missed this particular bug. Though, granted, it's a good lesson in how to write tests better than most of us do.

Comment: "To be fair, a common way to test `<<` is with `std::cout`" — But another common way is with `std::ostringstream` so that you can verify the results. And OP would have found at least one "stupid" bug either way... unless his test was written in the form `myptr << std::cout`. ;)

Answer (score 11):

Let's have a look at some examples where it fails.

#### Rule of Three

You have not correctly over written the assignment operator.

```
ptr::unq<int>   x(new int(5));
ptr::unq<int>   y;

y = x;   // This is broken. You should look up rule of three.
```

The above code compiles. **BUT** is broken. This pointer will get deleted twice. In debug mode on my compiler it even shows this.

```
> ./a.out
a.out(7619,0x10f20c5c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff597c02ac0: pointer 
being freed was not allocated
a.out(7619,0x10f20c5c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>
```

#### Rule of Five

Now I try and use the move operators.

```
ptr::unq<int>   x(new int(5));
ptr::unq<int>   y;

y = std::move(x);   // This compiles. Which is a surprise.
```

But again when we run the code and generate an error.

```
> ./a.out
a.out(7619,0x10f20c5c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff597c02ac0: pointer 
being freed was not allocated
a.out(7619,0x10f20c5c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>
```

This suggests that something not quite correct is happening.

#### Implicit construction

You have an implicit construction problem.

Imagine this situation:

```
void doWork(ptr::unq<int> data)
{
    std::cout << "Do Work\n";
}

int main()
{
    int*  x = new int(5);
    doWork(x);            // This creates a ptr::unq<int> object.
                          // This object is destroyed at the call which will
                          // call delete on the pointer passed.

    delete x;             // This means this is an extra delete on the pointer
                          // which makes it a bug.
}
```

Running this we get:

```
> ./a.out
a.out(7619,0x10f20c5c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff597c02ac0: pointer 
being freed was not allocated
a.out(7619,0x10f20c5c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>
```

I like that you added a bool operators

```
        operator bool const () { return (obj != nullptr) ? true : false; }
```

Couple of things wrong:

- The `const` is in the wrong place.
- The test is a bit verbose. You are testing a boolean expression `(obj != nullptr)` then using a trinary operator to extract that value, much easier to simply return the expression.
- You also need to use `explicit`. Otherwise we can use the comparison to compare pointers in a way that we do not intend.

  ```
  ptr::unq<int>    uniqueInt(new int(5));
  ptr::unq<flt>    uniqueFlt(new flt(12.0));

  if (uniqueInt == uniqueFlt) {
      std::cout << "I bet this prints\n";
  }
  ```

Now when I run:

```
 > ./a.out
 I bet this prints
 >
```

To prevent this you should tack on `explicit`. This prevents unrequired conversions.

```
 explicit operator bool () const { return obj != nullptr; }
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't notice the assignment bug with unq. I did notice in your linked article that you mentioned making a smart pointer implementation for learning is a bad idea because it is hard to get it correct in all contexts. While I somewhat agree (in hindsight, after seeing all of my errors) I purposefully made this a _subset_ of a full implementation, where this is in no way intended to be the full thing. Would you agree this is fine to do? 
Further, other than the specific errors mentioned so far, do you have any critiques of the overall structure of the implementation? Thanks!

Comment: @sjh919 I think writing a smart pointers is a good exercise for any programmer as it teaches a lot. **BUT** I think it is also very hard and something you should try once you have a lot of experience already. I think it is way too difficult for a beginner.